# Avoid render html node on react using react-lazyload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've added `react-lazyload` for my component, but there is an specific place where my component doesn't need the "*lazy load*" mode. I've been searching on [react-lazyload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload) documentation about any prop there that can inactive the lazy load there but there it wasn't.

How can I achieve this?

**MyComponent.jsx**

```
export const BgImage = observer(({ content }) => {
  const { background_image } = content
    
  return (
    <>
      <LazyLoad once={true} debounce={500} height={300}>
        <MyImage altText="test"/>
      </LazyLoad>
      <Noscript>
        <MyImage altText="test" />
      </Noscript>
    </>
  )
})
```

An `if` statement it's the only way to achieve this? or is there any prop that I can set to `<Lazyload...` in order to avoid the feature for specific components?

Comment: If there is nothing on the doc to do so, an `if` might be the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

LazyLoad is a Wrapper , these are the props which you can pass , a you can see there is no option to turn it off but you can run it once

```
LazyLoad.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  classNamePrefix: PropTypes.string,
  once: PropTypes.bool,
  height: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string]),
  offset: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.number,
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number)
  ]),
  overflow: PropTypes.bool,
  resize: PropTypes.bool,
  scroll: PropTypes.bool,
  children: PropTypes.node,
  throttle: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.bool]),
  debounce: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.bool]),
  placeholder: PropTypes.node,
  scrollContainer: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.object]),
  unmountIfInvisible: PropTypes.bool,
  style: PropTypes.object
};
```

But you can do a condition check like below

```
export const BgImage = observer(({ content }) => {
  const { background_image } = content
    
  return (
    <>
      {/*You can put condition here*/}
      {true ? <LazyLoad once={true} debounce={500} height={300}>
        <MyImage altText="test"/>
      </LazyLoad> : <MyImage altText="test"/>}
      
      <Noscript>
        <MyImage altText="test" />
      </Noscript>
    </>
  )
})
```